# Can we forecast a random-walk time series with another one?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, random-walk

I have two time series that follow a random walk behaviour. I would like to use the one I know to forecast the other one.

Suppose there is a strong correlation between them with $\text{lag}=k$, for example. This lag would permit me to forecast one because I have the information $k$ days before from the other one, even if it is a random walk.

Does it make sense? The problem I intuitively observe is that I'm trying to forecast a random evolution.

Comment: I think you want a [tag:var] model.

Comment: I already know ARMA and ARIMA, and it looks like I've missed an important and interesting model. Thank you

Comment: @Nico401 VAR is just AR of ARMA but with vectors. same general idea.

Comment: With random walks, it's important to take first differences and avoid some possibly common pitfalls... There's a well known result that if you have two randomly generated random walks, you can regress one on the other and consistently get "statistically significant" results using classic regression techniques even though there's 0 actual relationship.

Comment: Actually, if you have two non-stationary which cointegrate then you should a) look at a VECM or b) First you'll have to check  whether or not the series cointegrate. If they do not cointegrate you should take first differences of the variables and set-up a VAR for first differences. If they do cointegrate you can continue with the VAR in levels.

Comment: @MatthewGunn. That does not hold if the series cointegrate.

Comment: @Plissken Yeah, good points. How one should proceed depends on whether the series are cointegrated. There are formal tests, but often, some knowledge/intuition about the structure of the problem can help guide (eg. aggregate consumption and aggregate dividends are often assumed to be cointegrated). If two series are cointegrated, a VAR in first differences will miss that the cointegrating relationship will tend to push the two series back together if they drift too far apart in levels.

Comment: @plissken . Personally I do not see how cointegration tests are useful for forecasting purposes.  They cannot say with 100% certainty whether the series are actually cointergrated ir not.  Why not run 2 models, a VAR in levels and another in differences than simply choose the model with the best forecasting performance? or better yet produce an optimal forecast combination between the two?

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld. You'll still need to estimate the coefficients in your VAR model and regressing an I(1) variable on another I(1) variable will result in a spurious regression unless there exists a cointegrating relationship between the two series. Another reason for incorporating the long-run information when forecasting is that some papers have found that it increases forecast precision, especially for longer horizons, see e.g. "Forecasting with factor-augmented error correction models", availble here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207013000368

Comment: The reason I mentioned it in the fist place was to add information to the comments by gung and MatthewGunn.

Comment: @plissken If you regressed I(1) on I(1) and they were not cointigrated your residuals would not be stationary.  If you tested the performance of such a model out-of-sample it would perform poorly.  Failure to reject a null in a cointegration test could be a reflection of not having enough data or lack of power, it does not necessarily mean the null is true.  Vice versa, rejection of the null does not provide 100% support for the alternative.  As such, if the primary goal is forecasting, there is no reason to forgo testing both models out-of-sample on the basis of a cointegration test.

Comment: This is not to say cointegration tests are useless, they make  a lot of sense when used in regression frameworks that attempt to test economic models or establish causality.  In such cases, the researcher should have to prove, beyond a reasonable significance level, that the time series in use are actually or are not actually cointegrated.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld "If you regressed I(1) on I(1) and they were not cointegrated your residuals would not be stationary. If you tested the performance of such a model out-of-sample it would perform poorly." That is exactly what I stated in my previous comment. Further, I cannot really follow your reasoning. You can always get poor forecasting accuracy but you can also get good in-sample forecasting accuracy from a wrong model. The point is that you would not know whether or not your models parameters would be consistent and if your model would be nonsense. The second line of reasoning holds

Comment: for any model and test you can think of. Let's just agree to disagree on this one and leave it with that as otherwise this discussion could go on for a considerable amount of time :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally used a **VAR(q)** model. It fits very well my goal, in effect my two time series are interdependent and I can use one to forecast the other one.

When I've build my model with R, I had to specify my two time series and to find the good q value. AIC and BIC criterions are good to do that.